# How can I drive this 4 coil motor?

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, coil

[image][image]

I have a motor that I pulled off a broken Dyson v8 hoover. When I removed the broken driver circuit(the capacitors snapped off) I found this motor layout with 4 coils and no wiring pattern. How can I connect this motor together in order that I can drive it with a constant DC power source. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What makes you think that you can?

Comment: You mention that you want to drive a Dyson motor with *"a constant DC power source"* Before we can answer it would be nice to have some idea of the electronic background knowledge you have.

Comment: I’m not sure if I can drive this motor, I have basic knowledge in electronic motors. By a constant dc power source I really mean connect it to an Arduino through some sort of driver circuit and a dc battery and maybe PWM a signal through to control the speed of the motor. Do I need a certain type of ESC or something?

Comment: You probably need to generate a specially shaped AC waveform for the motors. My guess is the round black wheel is a permanent magnet which you have to attract and repel at the right time. All in all I would not like to try reverse engineer it unless I had a working version to measure on.

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense. How do you reckon I should wire the coils though?

Comment: Reverse engineering that driver circuit, or even repairing it, is probably the easiest way. It's designed for the job. Once you understand how it works. you'll know what to do.

Comment: If it's a Dyson then it can't be a "hoover". I know that you mean vacuum cleaner but not everyone will. Your two photographs seem to be identical. Is there a reason for two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's a permanent magnet in the rotor:

Rotate it and record the generated voltage waveforms of the coils. Insert also some load to suppress parasitic oscillations. The you see what's needed for that power which is wasted in the load resistors.

If there's no permanent magnet the case is complex. It can be a reluctance motor or even an induction motor. They are complex. You need an expert to test how they should be run. I do not try to make guesses. Induction motor for ex. needs a proper multiphase AC waveform. The phase shift can be generated by a capacitor but that's not necessary with modern DC to AC conversion electronics.

But if it has permanent magnet rotor still a basic knowledge of electric machine theory including the math is a must. Without it you cannot decide which simplifications of the waveforms are not disastrous.

You should search for brushless motor drive methods and circuits.

Comment: ... and if it's a variable reluctance motor? Easy to check for a magnet.

Comment: It can be but I do not believe it. But you are right, its possible the image doesn't prove anything. I'll fix the answer.